# Why D7 creates two tables when i add one custom fields in user registration?

Tags: entities

I created few custom fields for user registration in Drupal 7.

When I add the "First name" field, two tables are created: field_data_field_first_name, and field_revision_field_first_name.

Why are there two tables, if they contain the same data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the answer on your question on [Duplicate data in field_data* and field_revision* tables](http://drupal.org/node/1279440). In particular, see [this comment](http://drupal.org/node/1279440#comment-5057558):

> The field_revision tables store the revision id, which never changes in these tables. The field_data tables store the node's current revision id and does not store old revision data. Basically the field_data tables only ever contain 1 entry per node. The field_revisions table will contain the number of revisions you've created, preserving the revision data. So if you never use revisions, then yes, the tables will contain identical data.
>
> Since revisions are a core part of Drupal I don't think there's anything you can do about this. You can probably delete the contents of the field_revision tables (please test first, don't take my word for it!), but as soon as you start creating/editing nodes the field_revision tables will repopulate.